# Determine if astro (or other file managers) is installed or not in Android

Tags: android, file-manager

I would like to determine if any file manager is installed or not. If not installed any, then offer user to install one.

Comment: You cannot do this in general.  At most you could check for the existence of specific known application packages (Astro, official builds of Open Intents, etc) using the PackageManager or check for anything which might handle a known semi-standard Intent.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you have to know Launch activity name and package name for each file manager that you want to check. After that you can do something like this:

```
String packageName = "com.metago.astro" 
String activityName = packageName+"."+[LaunchActivityName]; 

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, activityName));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if(list.size() > 0){
   startActivity(intent);
}else{
   String googlePlayURL= "market://details?id=" + packageName;
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(googlePlayURL)));
}
```